# Can 'quod' refer to the previous speaker?

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

It is quite common to start a Latin sentence with *quod*, referring to the matter discussed in the previous sentence.
In a dialogue, can one use it to refer to the previous thing even if it was uttered by someone else?
That is, can the relative pronoun starting a sentence refer to another speaker and essentially mean "the thing you just said"?

Side question:
Which pronoun would be the best fit here if not the relative one?
*Iste*?

Comment: llmavirta: Is "someone else" the second or third person, in the sentence? Is it a   "previous sentence" or a previous clause--would it matter? Allen & Greenough p.572: "inter inanimum et animal  hoc maxime interest, quod animal agit aliquid" = "this is the chief difference between an inanimate object and an animal, that an animal aims at something" (Acad. 2.37). This could be adapted: "inter inanimum et te....quod tu dixisti aliquid" = "between an object and you....that you have said something". To reference information from a third-party, Cicero took a different path :"is unde te

Comment: llmavirta: audisse dicis" = "the man whence (from whom) you heard it", (Ad Quintum Fratrem 2.285). This may be irrelevant to the main point that you seek; but, I like this use of "unde" and have been looking for an opportunity to include it, somewhere.

Comment: @tony It makes no difference to me what role the "someone else" plays in the sentence. It is only a matter of changing speakers and whether the relative pronoun can refer across such a change.

Comment: llmavirta: Translating "the thing you just said" = "id, quod modo dixisti" (where "id" = "that [thing]); A says this to B: chappie, B is the "someone else"; the speaker has changed from A to B; "id" is "referring to the matter discussed in the previous sentence". If the "role" i.e. the number of parties involved is irrelevant, then I fail to see the difficulty. If you disagree, fine; at least enjoy the superlative Latin of Cicero.